# Apache doesn't load static folder for Django project

Tags: django, apache, virtualenv, mod-wsgi

I have a Django 1.4.5 project called `mp` which I'm trying to run on my localhost using Apache 2.4. Following the official tutorial for Django with `mod_wsgi` 
([How to use Django with Apache and mod_wsgi](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/)) I managed to display my Django page when I visit `http://127.0.0.1:8801/`.

My project folder `mp` is located in `/opt/masterportal/mp`, and the static files are located in `/opt/masterportal/mp/mp/static`.

This is my `masterportal.conf` file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`:

```
Listen 8081
<VirtualHost *:8081>
     ServerAdmin my@mail.adress

     XSendFilePath /opt/masterportal/mp/mp/uploads/
     <Files *.*>
         XSendFile On
     </Files>

     WSGIDaemonProcess masterportal python-path=/opt/masterportal/mp:/opt/masterportal/mp/env/dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages
     WSGIProcessGroup masterportal
     WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/masterportal/mp/mp/apache/wsgi.py

     Alias /static /opt/masterportal/mp/mp/static

     <Directory /opt/masterportal/mp/mp/static>
        Require all granted
     </Directory>

     <Location />
        WSGIProcessGroup masterportal
        Require all granted
     </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

However, the website at `http://127.0.0.1:8801` can't find any of the static files. This is odd, because the exact same project works on the server of my university (where I don't have access to the apache configuration). So there must be something wrong with my Apache configuration, but I can't see what. I'm desperate for help.

**Some general information:** I'm using Django 1.4.5 (because this is the version on the university server), and Apache 2.4. The project runs in a virtualenv located here `/opt/masterportal/mp/env`. I also tried it with `Alias /static/` instead of `Alias /static`, but that didn't work either. My apache2.conf is still original - I made no changes there.

**Edit:** Here's my configuration for the site in `/etc/apache2/conf-available/`:

```
    <Location "/mp/2015/suse">
        ProxyPass https://my-computername:8081/
        ProxyPassReverse https://my-computername:8081/
        RequestHeader set X-FORWARDED-PROTOCOL ssl
        RequestHeader set X-FORWARDED-SSL on
    </Location>
```

Comment: What happens when you go to the path of a static file in your browser? Is this a simple 404, or you can get more logs?

Comment: @RaphaelLaurent It's a simple 404, no more logs.

Answer (score 1):

Try to move the lines

```
Alias /static /opt/masterportal/mp/mp/static

<Directory /opt/masterportal/mp/mp/static>
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

before

```
 WSGIDaemonProcess masterportal python-path=/opt/masterportal/mp:/opt/masterportal/mp/env/dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages
 WSGIProcessGroup masterportal
 WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/masterportal/mp/mp/apache/wsgi.py
```

because the link with /static/some_static_files... might be forwared to the wsgi app instead of pointing to the static directory.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately it doesn't work either.